# Prove that $\partial A$ is a cutset of connected $X$ if $\operatorname{Int}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Int}(X - A)$ are nonempty

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Exercise 6.23 (p.202) of *Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied* by C Adams and R Franzosa asks:

> Let $X$ be a connected topological space and $A$ be a subset of $X$. Prove that if $\operatorname{Int}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Int}(X - A)$ are nonempty, then $\partial A$ is a cutset, and the pair of sets, $\operatorname{Int}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Int}(X - A)$, is a separation of $X - \partial A$.

According to the book, a subset $S$ of a topological space $X$ is called a *cutset* of $X$ if $X - S$ is disconnected. A cutset of $X$ is said to *separate* $X$.

---

Here is my incomplete answer: If the definition of the cutset doesn't require that a cutset be the minimum of all possible cutsets, so the proof is straight forward. I need to prove the following conjectures:

1. $\operatorname{Int}(A)\cap \partial A = \emptyset$
2. $\operatorname{Int}(X-A)\cap \partial A = \emptyset$
3. $\operatorname{Int}(A)\cap \operatorname{Int}(X-A) = \emptyset$
4. $\operatorname{Int}(A)\cup \partial A \cup \operatorname{Int}(X-A)= X$

I could prove 1 and 3, but unfortunately I can't prove 2 and 4.

Could someone please help me with these questions: Is my procedure still correct if we require the cutset be the minimum of all possible cutsets? If so, how to prove 2 and 4 above?

EDIT - Is it correct to say "If $A\subset X \implies Cl(A)\subset X$"?

Comment: Hint: $\partial A = \partial(X-A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$, we automatically have $\operatorname{bdry}A=\operatorname{bdry}(X\setminus A)$. Thus, if you know that $(\operatorname{int}A)\cap\operatorname{bdry}A=\varnothing$, then you also know that

$$\big(\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)\big)\cap\operatorname{bdry}A=\big(\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)\big)\cap\operatorname{bdry}(X\setminus A)=\varnothing\;,$$

where the last step follows by applying $(1)$ to $X\setminus A$ instead of $A$.

More directly, $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$, and $\operatorname{bdry}A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, so $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)\cap\operatorname{cl}A=\varnothing$.

For $(4)$, note that

$$\begin{align*}
(\operatorname{int}A)\cup\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)&=(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)\cup\big(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)\big)\\
&=X\setminus\big((\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)\big)\\
&=X\setminus\operatorname{bdry}A\;.
\end{align*}$$

I usually take $(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$ as the definition of $\operatorname{bdry}A$; if you’re using one of the various equivalent definitions, your first step should probably be to prove that it’s equivalent to this one.

---

The definition of *cutset* does not require any kind of minimality.

Comment: To complete the proof I need to know if this statement is correct: "If $A\subset X \implies Cl(A)\subset X$". Is the statement correct? Thank you.

Comment: @AlphaE: Yes: $X$ is the ambient space, in which everything is happening.