# Boundary disconnects connected space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I need to show that a boundary of an open subset $\emptyset \neq A\subset X$ whis isn't dense in a connected space X, disconnects X.

Any hints how should I start?

Comment: So do you mean $X\setminus\partial A$ is disconnected?

Comment: Hint: Find two open sets whose union is the entire space.  I'm willing to give another hint, but I'll let you see if you have ideas on some of the open sets.

Comment: But if $X$ is connected, then those 2 open sets shouldn't be disjoint?

Comment: I am trying to do something with $X\setminus clA \cup A$ but it won't give the entire space..

Comment: I think that the space you should be considering is $X$ without the boundary of $A$.

Comment: I thought about it, but I have no idea what other open set I should add to get the entire $X$. Still thinking.

Comment: The problem isn't asking you to show $X$ is disconnected.  It's asking you to show a different space is disconnected.

Comment: They want me to show that $X \setminus bd(A)$ is disconnected. So I can take two sets (which aren't empty, because $A$ isn't dense in $X$, then $cl(A) \neq X$). $X \setminus bd(A) = A \cup X \setminus cl(A)$. $A$ is open and $X \setminus cl(A)$ is also open, because $cl(A)$ is closed.

Comment: Now, you're on the right track.

Comment: Should I show something more? I showed that $X \setminus bd(A)$ is disconnected. So I think this is what I was supposed to show...

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279993/prove-that-partial-a-is-a-cutset-of-connected-x-if-operatornameinta) is essentially the same question; you might take a look at the progress made by the person asking it and the further information in my answer to it.